# How to delete all orders

Tags: orders, sql, magento-2.2.5, delete

I want to delete all order from magento 2.2.5 
i used that code but it didnt work... any advice?

```
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

# Clean order history
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;

# Clean order infos
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;

# Clean cart infos
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;

# Reset indexes (if you want your orders number start back to 1
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_invoice_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_order_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_shipment_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_creditmemo_1;


SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: might be helpful please try with this https://marketplace.magento.com/raveinfosys-deleteorder.html

Comment: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-delete-orders

Comment: i used them but it crashes all web...

Comment: have you checked with the mageplaza extension?

Comment: Yeap now all working fine!!! thank you for your advice!!

Comment: well now i click on item and i trying to delete it but it still there...

Answer (score 1):

Create your own custom module.
And use method `delete` of `class Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface`. 
That would be the safest method to do so.